# Sum by two variables

Tags: r, sum

I have one dataframe:

```
       Date  area      sales
1     201204 shanghai    23
2     201204 beijing     25
3     201204 beijing     16
4     201205 shanghai    55
5     201205 beijing     17
6     201205 shanghai    16
```

What I want to output is a table as follows:

```
Date   shanghai  beijing 
201204  23        41
201205  71        17
```

How would I do this in R?

Comment: This is not a good StackOverflow question. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [StackOverflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810).

Comment: I looked up the aggregate function.But I believe there is a way to get  this easier.Now I got answers,thanks!

Answer (score 11):

In base R (for `sum`) there's `xtabs`:

```
> xtabs(sales ~ Date + area, mydf)
        area
Date     beijing shanghai
  201204      41       23
  201205      17       71
```

To get it as a `data.frame`, wrap it in `as.data.frame.matrix`.

---

To update this with the approach that is making the rounds these days, you can also use a combination of "dplyr" (for aggregation) and "tidyr" (for reshaping), like this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
  group_by(Date, area) %>% 
  summarise(sales = sum(sales)) %>% 
  spread(area, sales)
# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# 
#     Date beijing shanghai
# 1 201204      41       23
# 2 201205      17       71
```

Answer (score 5):

This is cannon fodder for `reshape2::dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
# assuming your data is called `D`
dcast(Date~area, value.var = 'sales', fun.aggregate = sum, data = D)
```